# Runtime.ImportModuleError - Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

**error message**

```
undefined ERROR Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'"}
```

**folder structure**

src

- handler.ts -> fn.getAll

**template.yaml**

```
GetAll:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  Handler: handler.getAll
  CodeUri: dist/out-tsc
  Policies:
    - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
        TableName: !Ref master
  Environment:
    Variables:
      USE_EVENT_BRIDGE: !Ref UseEventBridge
  Events:
    Api1:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        Path: /getAll
        Method: get
```

**Output folder:**

dist/out-tsc

- handler.js -> fn.getAll

After typescript compile using tsc. output files are generated at targeted location. In each JS handler file i have tslib require statement. Below error message denotes the same. When I click on the tslib it refers to the node modules perfectly. How can I overcome this?

I have updated the `tsconfig.json` with below options in compileroptions. Installed tslib in node modules

```
"paths": {
  "tslib": ["node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"]
}
```

**Error:**

```
START RequestId: 820d8905-61f3-4045-9704-3cc7bd4901df Version: $LATEST
2021-02-12T11:18:32.904Z
undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'","
    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)","
    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)","
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)","
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)","
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)","
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)","
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)","
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)","
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"]}
```

Comment: I had to was running node version 12 and so i downgraded my tsconfig.json es version to es2017